# Could an increase in heart strength result in an increase in systolic blood pressure?

Tags: exercise, cardiology, heart

If someone begins intense cardio training and develops their heart muscle, it seems to me that the increase in volume of blood that the heart can pump with every beat might manifest as a higher systolic blood pressure.  Is that right?  If not, why not?

Comment: If that were true then athletes would tend to have hypertension and sedentary individuals would tend to have low BP. What has your research revealed about that?

Comment: @CareyGregory For some reason I hadn't tried searching Google for that, but I just did a quick search and it seems to confirm my suspicion: https://www.runnersworld.com/health-injuries/a20846111/do-athletes-have-higher-or-lower-blood-pressure/ "If you break the results down further, you find that strength-trained athletes have slightly higher blood pressure than endurance-trained athletes."  I have been doing serious weight training for the past few months and my systolic blood pressure is now averaging around 130, and I was trying to figure out why, as I don't fit into any of the risk groups.

Comment: Interestingly, I just checked a doctor's report from a check-up I did just before I started the weight training when I was ~10lbs heavier than I am now and my systolic BP was lower (126) while my diastolic was much(?) higher (76 back then, avg. ~63 now).

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved (and meet site requirements) if you added the link in your comment to the question itself. The question should contain everything necessary to understand it and see that you did prior research. Reading comments shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @NathanWailes To get this question reopened and the downvote removed, simply edit the question to add the link and the quote you have in your comment above to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Intense cardio training over sufficiently prolonged time tend to incerease the capacity of your cadiovascular system to carry oxygen to the muscle. One aspect (among many) is the increase in volume of the left chamber of the heart which is seen in professional athletes of enurance sports.
(https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4771151/)
Blood pressure rises in excercise (not easy to measure, but can be observed in stress tests, https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/full/10.1161/hs0901.095395) to accomodate the need for extra oxygen. As the excerise continue, the arteries diameter get larger and it helps in regulating the blood pressure. It suppose to go back to normal as exercise stops and it actually goes lower than usual (https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1161/01.cir.83.5.1557 since the blood vessels remain large. You can also test it on yourself) for a few minutes after stopping. Prolonged aerobic training helps to reduce hypertension.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Unreferenced claims can be challenged and lead to deletion of your answer.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your comment. I appreciate the policy and will try to adhere to it. What I wrote above is really common knowledge to any person working in the field.

Comment: @Chris Rogers - I have added references.